# How can I figure out if user input is a valid sharename for windows net share?

Tags: windows, powershell, share

I have a powershell script that is querying the user to input a name for a windows shared folder. I am setting up the shared folder using Windows' [Net Share](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490712.aspx). I want to do something along the lines of:

`$dest = "C:\Syncer"
 $sharename = Read-Host
 net share $sharename=$dest`

However, Windows will not recognize all input strings identifier as a valid sharename. For example, giving it the input `Aa.,` will not work. How can I figure out if the user's input works as a valid identifier?

Comment: To be honest what is probably your best option that I can think of is to determine what defines a valid share name, and then perform a RegEx match to validate it, and put it in a `Do{$sharename=read-host}while($sharename -notmatch "RegEx Pattern")` loop. Maybe test to see if that share already exists too with a `test-path` in the `while` conditions

Comment: I've not found any restrictions on fileshare names (`shiXXX_netname` member of structures) in [MS docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb525395.aspx), it just has to be Unicode string. Can you try to create share using `New-SMBShare` (PS 3.0) or [WIN32_Share](http://serverfault.com/questions/581585/create-network-shared-folder-using-powershell-on-windows-7) WMI class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ TheMadTechnician gives the good solution, I just bring the fact that Server Message Block (SMB), one version of which was also known as Common Internet File System (CIFS) supports [Universal Naming Convention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg465305.aspx) (UNC) names.

Here is the summary, you are interested in share-name :

```
 UNC                = "\\" host-name "\" share-name  [ "\" object-name ]
 host-name          = "[" IPv6address ‘]" / IPv4address / reg-name; IPv6address, IPv4address, and reg-name as specified in [RFC3986] 
 share-name         = 1*80pchar
 pchar              = %x20-21 / %x23-29 / %x2D-2E / %x30-39 / %x40-5A / %x5E-7B / %x7D-FF  
 object-name        = *path-name [ "\" file-name ]
 path-name          = 1*255pchar
 file-name          = 1*255fchar [ ":" stream-name [ ":" stream-type ] ]
 fchar              = %x20-21 / %x23-29 / %x2B-2E / %x30-39 / %x3B / %x3D / %x40-5B / %x5D-7B /                            %x7D-FF 
 stream-name        = *schar
 schar              = %x01-2E / %x30-39 / %x3B-5B /%x5D-FF
 stream-type        = 1*schar
```

[Here](http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=2285&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) is a result for the Regex expression, I think tha google can give you more.